# Передать данные с editView в html поле ввода

Tags: android, java

Кто знает как такое сделать? Делаю поиск по слову, и мне нужно что бы слово вписывалось в форму на одном из сайтов, как переадресовать его на форму?

**UPD:**
Ну значит вот какой вопрос, у меня есть поле для ввода текста, я ввожу текст и нажимаю отправить, дальше после нажатия отправить у меня данные передаются на сайт с формой для ввода например как получить запрос в гугл, ввожу вопрос у себя на телефоне, отправляю а запрос передается в поле ввода в гугле и ищитеся уже там, ну а варианты вывожу у себя на телефоне.

**Буду юзать JSON, всем спасибо...**

Comment: Поконкретнее! Где делаете поиск по слову, что надо, в чем проблема. Уж не поленитесь напишите подробнее

Comment: в апдейте добавил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=ru-RU) вам в помощь

Comment: нет, мне нужно не для гугла это делать, у меня произвольный сайт задан.

Comment: ну а что трудно посмотреть какие данные передаются и по какому урлу когда вы ручками отправляете форму, сделать такой же запрос, а потом уже его парсить.

Comment: да там ничего не понятно, можно хотя бы наводку на что и куда смотреть?

Comment: ну к примеру в хроме посмотри какой запрос шлётся. или сырцы формы, скрипта, я ж не всевидец что там надо